# null object reference while trying to retrieve Firebase class Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a model class to store Firebase User information. Inside of the model class I have a HashMap to store all of the data inside. Once I have stored the data, the I push the Hashmap into the Firebase database. The values store fine, but I cannot access the values. Every time I try to access them, I get an error saying that I am attempting to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference.

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot ChildSnapshot, String s) {

// These two lines of code give the error.
User author = ChildSnapshot.child("profile").getValue(User.class);
String author_username = author.getUsername();
```

These give me the error. I am attempting to grab data from the child of the snapshot. Why is this giving me an error? Is there a better way to do this?

JSON Firebase snapshot:

[image]

Model class:

```
//TODO model class for the user. This way I can set the values for each user. I will be adding more values in the future.

public class User {


public HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
public User() {

}
    public User(String username) {
    hashMap.put("username",username);

}


public String getUsername(){
    return hashMap.get("username");
}
}
```

Comment: post your Firebase  DB snap

Comment: I edited it and added the snapshot lines

Comment: i mean your Firebase database.

Comment: @Matthew You can get this database snapshot by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: can you show your model class?

Comment: Added my model class :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody else was struggling with this issue, I wanted to give an answer. Inside of my ChildEventListener, the profile is the key in this situation so when I use `ChildSnapshot.child("profile").getValue(User.class)` it returns a null value. Also, (I'm not quite sure why this is) the value of the username was stored in a different class called User_message which was used to store the message. so my updated code looks something like this:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot ChildSnapshot, String s) {


User_message author = ChildSnapshot.getValue(User_message.class);
String author_username = author.getUsername();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and spent more than 5 hours. I added Default Constructor of the model and this solves my problem.

```
public class User {

public String email;
public String name;

public User() {
}

public User(String email, String name) {
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
}}
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already had a default constructor. My spacing in the class was just bad so it is hard to see.